# Webclient.UploadFile() uploads file to destination, but throws an error

Tags: .net, powershell, error-handling

So I have this code to upload a file to the destination after the xml is generated. Checking the server I see that the file is there with the correct contents, but from one of my catch blocks I get the "An error occurred that could not be resolved." I cannot tell if this is a critical error because I do not know what the error is. The file is at least uploaded, but I would like to figure out this error so I can resolve it. Is there a way to know what error is being thrown here?

```
try {
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $rawResponse = $wc.UploadFile("someURIhere", "Post", $File)
    $resp = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString($rawResponse)
    Write-Host $resp
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $Request = $_.Exception
    Write-host "Exception caught: $Request"
    $crapMessage = ($_.Exception.Message).ToString().Trim()
    Write-Output $crapMessage
}
catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred that could not be resolved."
}
```

Comment: Could you run the following after getting the error and edit your post with the output please `$Error[0].Exception.PSObject.Properties | select Name,Value | FL *`. If the file is uploading okay, I suspect the error is happening because of this line - `$resp = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString($rawResponse)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your *2nd* catch block is hit, you know it's *not* an `WebException`.

Your script should produce an error because of this invalid line:

```
$resp = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString($rawResponse)
```

What you probably wanted to write is:

```
$resp = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($rawResponse)
```

Also, you're safest if you use this instead, to make sure you're using the right encoding:

```
$resp = $wc.Encoding.GetString($rawResponse)
```

Comment: It was coming from this I tried it with  ``` $resp = $wc.Encoding.GetString($rawResponse) ``` and it worked with no error.